# Autocomplete for non-TypeScript npm packages doesn't work in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ide, phpstorm

How can I make my TypeScript project in PhpStorm autocomplete npm packages that don't use TypeScript?

I'm using this npm package called [steamcommunity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steamcommunity) and it does not use TypeScript.

As you can see in the first image the autocomplete doesn't work for this package *(which is absolutely frustrating for me cause I have to constantly look into the documentation)*:

[image: autocomplete not working]

But when I manually change the `index.js` file of the package (`node_modules/steamcommunity/index.js`) to `index.ts`, the autocomplete suddenly starts working:

[image: autocomplete working]

Is there a better solution than to manually modify the file in `node_modules`?

EDIT: This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I discovered a different kind of "minor solution" that basically doesn't solve it in general but anyway... it's auto-generating the types for the package yourself and creating a pull request for the *TypeScript-less* package...

I discovered this npm package called [dts-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-gen) that auto-generates the types for a given package automatically and it works almost perfectly and it recognized almost all the methods from different files and it put it all together.

This is how I used it:

1. `npm i -g dts-gen`
2. `npm i -g steamcommunity`
3. `dts-gen -m steamcommunity`

This generated a single file called `steamcommunity.d.ts` which contains all the types of different classes, functions and variables. I forked the original package repository, renamed the generated file to `index.d.ts` and put it into the root folder, pushed it and created a pull request.

Comment: So I _typed_ the [whole thing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/steamcommunity) myself, but that still doesn't solve the issue for other packages obiously

Comment: the issue is tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52133, please follow it for updates